# How to Integrate paypal gateway in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, paypal

Am following this site   http://www.17educations.com/laravel/paypal-integration-in-laravel/
If I run the project I have error like this, pls anybody say solution

> localhost/pay_pal/public/payment 
>  MethodNotAllowedHttpException in
>   RouteCollection.php line 219:
>
> localhost/pay_pal/public/payment/status 
>  FatalErrorException in
>   PaypalController.php line 18: Class
>   'App\Http\Controllers\BaseController' not found

Comment: it was only the route error try to change it to get method for testing if it is working.

Comment: I changed the route post method to get method but I still have error like this  FatalErrorException in PaypalController.php line 18:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\BaseController' not found

Comment: Can you show me the code line 18 at PaypalController.php?

Comment: class PaypalController extends BaseController
{

Comment: Change your extends BaseController to Controller

Comment: I changed but I have another error FatalErrorException in PaypalController.php line 25:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Config' not found

Comment: 25th line is $paypal_conf = Config::get('paypal');

Comment: add this under namespace ->use Config;

Comment: or $paypal_conf = \Config::get('paypal');

Comment: I tired both this error came
ErrorException in ApiContext.php line 113:
Argument 1 passed to PayPal\Rest\ApiContext::setConfig() must be of the type array, null given, called in C:\wamp\www\pay_pal\app\Http\Controllers\PaypalController.php on line 29 and defined

Comment: did you already configured?

Comment: I just installed and using composer

Comment: show me the line 29 code

Comment: 27)$paypal_conf = Config::get('paypal');
28)$this->_api_context = new ApiContext(new OAuthTokenCredential($paypal_conf['client_id'], $paypal_conf['secret']));
29)$this->_api_context->setConfig($paypal_conf['settings']);

Comment: add backslash in Config:: like this \Config::get('paypal');

Comment: I tried that also Now am put  backslash still I have that error

Comment: 27)$paypal_conf = \Config::get('paypal');
28)$this->_api_context = new ApiContext(new OAuthTokenCredential($paypal_conf['client_id'], $paypal_conf['secret']));
29)$this->_api_context->setConfig($paypal_conf['settings']);

Comment: ErrorException in ApiContext.php line 113:
Argument 1 passed to PayPal\Rest\ApiContext::setConfig() must be of the type array, null given, called in C:\wamp\www\pay_pal\app\Http\Controllers\PaypalController.php on line 29 and defined

Comment: check your line 113 looks like you did not configure properly

Comment: I just use this code "paypal/rest-api-sdk-php": "*" paste into composer.json then I use composer update in command prompt

Comment: I already have answered this question. Checkout it out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40372320/1528268).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Integrate Paypal Payment gateway in laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32900917/how-to-integrate-paypal-payment-gateway-in-laravel)