# How to Integrate Paypal Payment gateway in laravel?

Tags: laravel, paypal-sandbox, laravel-5.1, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal

How to Integrate Paypal Payment gateway in Laravel?
I tried this http://www.17educations.com/laravel/paypal-integration-in-laravel/
but config have some problem,Please anybody say some ideas

Comment: You can pull paypal sdk through composer, create a config file or hardcode your credentials and you are good to go. More info [here](http://learninglaravel.net/integrate-paypal-sdk-into-laravel-4-laravel-5/link) . I also suggest you should look @delatbabel 's answer . Omnipay can help you achieve merchant functionality with multiple providers with just one API.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Integrate paypal gateway in laravel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32886989/how-to-integrate-paypal-gateway-in-laravel)

Answer (score 8):

**Follow Bellow Few Step:**
**1)Install Laravel Application**
**2)Database Configuration**
**3)Install Required Packages**
**4)configuration paypal.php file** 
**5)create route** 
**6)create controller** 
**7)create view file**

**Step 1 : Install Laravel Application**
we are going from scratch, So we require to get fresh Laravel application using bellow command, So open your terminal OR command prompt and run bellow command:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```

**Step 2 : Database Configuration**
In this step, we require to make database configuration, you have to add
 following details on your .env file.
**1.Database Username**
**1.Database Password**
**1.Database Name**

In .env file also available host and port details, you can configure all details as in your system, So you can put like as bellow:
**.env**

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

**Step 3 : Install Required Packages**
We have required following 2 packages for integrate paypal payment in our laravel application.
add following two package in your composer.json file.

```
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.4",
"paypal/rest-api-sdk-php": "*",
```

then after run following command in your terminal. vendor:publish command is used to copy few configuration file in your application from vendor package file.

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```

after run this command, then after automatic create paypal.php file in your **config/paypal.php** path.

Step 4 : Configuration paypal.php file

```
&lt;?php

return array(
/** set your paypal credential **/
'client_id' =>'paypal client_id',
'secret' => 'paypal secret ID',
/**
* SDK configuration 
*/
'settings' => array(
    /**
    * Available option 'sandbox' or 'live'
    */
    'mode' => 'sandbox',
    /**
    * Specify the max request time in seconds
    */
    'http.ConnectionTimeOut' => 1000,
    /**
    * Whether want to log to a file
    */
    'log.LogEnabled' => true,
    /**
    * Specify the file that want to write on
    */
    'log.FileName' => storage_path() . '/logs/paypal.log',
    /**
    * Available option 'FINE', 'INFO', 'WARN' or 'ERROR'
    *
    * Logging is most verbose in the 'FINE' level and decreases as you
    * proceed towards ERROR
    */
    'log.LogLevel' => 'FINE'
    ),
);
```

**Step 5: Create Route**
In this is step we need to create route for paypal payment. so open your **routes/web.php** file and add following route.
**routes/web.php**

```
Route::get('paywithpaypal', array('as' => 'addmoney.paywithpaypal','uses' => 'AddMoneyController@payWithPaypal',));
Route::post('paypal', array('as' => 'addmoney.paypal','uses' => 'AddMoneyController@postPaymentWithpaypal',));
Route::get('paypal', array('as' => 'payment.status','uses' => 'AddMoneyController@getPaymentStatus',));
```

**Step 6: Create Controller**
In this point, now we should create new controller as AddMoneyController in this path **app/Http/Controllers/AddMoneyController.php**. this controller will manage layout and payment post request, So run bellow command for generate new controller:

```
php artisan make:controller AddMoneyController
```

Ok, now put bellow content in controller file:
**app/Http/Controllers/AddMoneyController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Validator;
use URL;
use Session;
use Redirect;
use Input;

/** All Paypal Details class **/
use PayPal\Rest\ApiContext;
use PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential;
use PayPal\Api\Amount;
use PayPal\Api\Details;
use PayPal\Api\Item;
use PayPal\Api\ItemList;
use PayPal\Api\Payer;
use PayPal\Api\Payment;
use PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls;
use PayPal\Api\ExecutePayment;
use PayPal\Api\PaymentExecution;
use PayPal\Api\Transaction;

class AddMoneyController extends HomeController
{

    private $_api_context;
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        /** setup PayPal api context **/
        $paypal_conf = \Config::get('paypal');
        $this->_api_context = new ApiContext(new OAuthTokenCredential($paypal_conf['client_id'], $paypal_conf['secret']));
        $this->_api_context->setConfig($paypal_conf['settings']);
    }



    /**
     * Show the application paywith paypalpage.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function payWithPaypal()
    {
        return view('paywithpaypal');
    }

    /**
     * Store a details of payment with paypal.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function postPaymentWithpaypal(Request $request)
    {
        $payer = new Payer();
        $payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

        $item_1 = new Item();

        $item_1->setName('Item 1') /** item name **/
            ->setCurrency('USD')
            ->setQuantity(1)
            ->setPrice($request->get('amount')); /** unit price **/

        $item_list = new ItemList();
        $item_list->setItems(array($item_1));

        $amount = new Amount();
        $amount->setCurrency('USD')
            ->setTotal($request->get('amount'));

        $transaction = new Transaction();
        $transaction->setAmount($amount)
            ->setItemList($item_list)
            ->setDescription('Your transaction description');

        $redirect_urls = new RedirectUrls();
        $redirect_urls->setReturnUrl(URL::route('payment.status')) /** Specify return URL **/
            ->setCancelUrl(URL::route('payment.status'));

        $payment = new Payment();
        $payment->setIntent('Sale')
            ->setPayer($payer)
            ->setRedirectUrls($redirect_urls)
            ->setTransactions(array($transaction));
            /** dd($payment->create($this->_api_context));exit; **/
        try {
            $payment->create($this->_api_context);
        } catch (\PayPal\Exception\PPConnectionException $ex) {
            if (\Config::get('app.debug')) {
                \Session::put('error','Connection timeout');
                return Redirect::route('addmoney.paywithpaypal');
                /** echo "Exception: " . $ex->getMessage() . PHP_EOL; **/
                /** $err_data = json_decode($ex->getData(), true); **/
                /** exit; **/
            } else {
                \Session::put('error','Some error occur, sorry for inconvenient');
                return Redirect::route('addmoney.paywithpaypal');
                /** die('Some error occur, sorry for inconvenient'); **/
            }
        }

        foreach($payment->getLinks() as $link) {
            if($link->getRel() == 'approval_url') {
                $redirect_url = $link->getHref();
                break;
            }
        }

        /** add payment ID to session **/
        Session::put('paypal_payment_id', $payment->getId());

        if(isset($redirect_url)) {
            /** redirect to paypal **/
            return Redirect::away($redirect_url);
        }

        \Session::put('error','Unknown error occurred');
        return Redirect::route('addmoney.paywithpaypal');
    }

    public function getPaymentStatus()
    {
        /** Get the payment ID before session clear **/
        $payment_id = Session::get('paypal_payment_id');
        /** clear the session payment ID **/
        Session::forget('paypal_payment_id');
        if (empty(Input::get('PayerID')) || empty(Input::get('token'))) {
            \Session::put('error','Payment failed');
            return Redirect::route('addmoney.paywithpaypal');
        }
        $payment = Payment::get($payment_id, $this->_api_context);
        /** PaymentExecution object includes information necessary **/
        /** to execute a PayPal account payment. **/
        /** The payer_id is added to the request query parameters **/
        /** when the user is redirected from paypal back to your site **/
        $execution = new PaymentExecution();
        $execution->setPayerId(Input::get('PayerID'));
        /**Execute the payment **/
        $result = $payment->execute($execution, $this->_api_context);
        /** dd($result);exit; /** DEBUG RESULT, remove it later **/
        if ($result->getState() == 'approved') { 

            /** it's all right **/
            /** Here Write your database logic like that insert record or value in database if you want **/

            \Session::put('success','Payment success');
            return Redirect::route('addmoney.paywithpaypal');
        }
        \Session::put('error','Payment failed');

        return Redirect::route('addmoney.paywithpaypal');
    }
  }
```

Now we are ready to run our example so run bellow command ro quick run:

```
php artisan serve
```

Now you can open bellow URL on your browser:

```
http://localhost:8000/paywithpaypal
```

please visit this toturials link..

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ly2xm_NM46g

http://laravelcode.com/post/how-to-integrate-paypal-payment-gateway-in-laravel-54

Comment: I followed your video to integrate paypal in my project with laravel 5.2, but I receive this error message : Argument 1 passed to PayPal\Rest\ApiContext::setConfig() must be of the type array ..... at this line : $this->_api_context->setConfig($paypal_conf['settings']);

Answer (score 3):

What are you trying to achieve with PayPal and what problems are you having?

I would advise avoiding the paypal SDK and instead use Omnipay from the PHP league.  See http://omnipay.thephpleague.com/ and https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-paypal

If you download the omnipay library you will see some examples in the various class headers.  You will need to implement calls to purchase() and then have a returnUrl and a cancelUrl, and in your returnUrl you will need to implement a call to completePurchase().

If you tell me what you're trying to achieve I can give you some code examples.

Comment: After 15 minutes of research, this is as clear as dirt. [Examples](https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-example) giving no example, [paypall](https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-paypal) does not explain how to use it. I don't even know what paypall do I need Express/Pro? In cases like this I relay on youtube, but there are no videos about it. What will you get if you use it?

Answer (score 1):

Well as of right now here are some simpler options for laravel:

1. Omnipay - Multiple Gateways but no subscriptions (great docs)
2. Payum - Multiple Gatways with subscriptions (docs suck)
3. [Srmklive/Paypal](https://github.com/srmklive/laravel-paypal) - Only paypal with subscriptions (great docs
   and very active)

The first 2 are framework agnostic, which means you can directly use them but you will have to configure it for laravel, but if you want the easy way around for laravel you should use a wrapper for laravel. Which means that you just have to work with the wrapper and not the library itself. There are tons of wrappers for both of them.

**For those who just want to work with paypal then look no further, Srmklive's paypal package is just awesome.**

Answer (score 0):

Well as of right now here are some simpler options for Paypal payment Gateway integration on Laravel:
[Tutorial link](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-58-paypal-integration-tutorialexample.html)

[Github Clone Paypal Gateway](https://github.com/savanihd/paypal-payment-gateway-integration-in-laravel-5.8)

```
$response = $provider->doExpressCheckoutPayment($data, $token, $payer_id)
$payment_status = $response['ACK']
$transaction_id = $response['PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONID']
```